# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a smooth scroll on the page but it didn't work. I have been trying another version of jQuery and looking for another error like this on stackoverflow but I still haven't understood what's happening. Thank you in advance!

```js
$('.page-scroll').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  var tujuan = $(this).attr('href');
  var elementujuan = $(tujuan);

  $('html , body').animate({
    scrollTop: elementujuan.offset().top - 50
  }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your first error? Seems to me you are an expert immortal coder!

Comment: You can't get the offset of an attribute. Try removing the attr() from first car declaration and make it just `var tujuan = $(this)`. And remove the 2nd var declaration. Then, use tujuan instead of elementujuan in scroll section

Comment: @WaisKamal ya i still following tutorial anyway hehe

Comment: @AjithGopi still didnt work sir. it is because i use bootstrap 3?